# Sitecore as document management

Tags: sharepoint, sitecore, document-management

I'm wondering if the SharePoint connector module is deprecated with the new version of Sitecore. I can see a lot of about Sitecore and SP 2007 / 2010. But seems not the case any more with Sitecore 7 and SharePoint 2013.

Is Sitecore now could be used as Document management too?

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of the **SharePoint Integration Framework (SPIF)** was released on July 18, 2014 and Sitecore states that it was "tested with Sitecore CMS 6.6.0 rev. 140410 (Service Pack 2) and Sitecore CMS 7.2 rev. 140526 (7.2 Update-2)."

You can find more information [here on SDN](http://sdn.sitecore.net/Products/SPIF/SPIF20/Release%20Notes/Release%20History.aspx).

Regarding your question of whether Sitecore could be used as a Document management tool, that depends on your requirements.  If you can model your Sitecore instance in such a way that supports your requirements, I would say, you can use Sitecore as a "document management" tool.  But if you're comparing directly to Sharepoint, I would say "no".  Sitecore is a CMS.  Sharepoint is a document management tool.  The SPIF exists to connect the two so that one does not replace the other.

Comment: So, if we would like to link document which can be consulted or downloaded linked to a product or whanever, it could be a solution. Even for the versioning, I think we could have more than one version, Right ? Even one document in multiple language if the site is multilingual.